# Uploading a empty folder to github

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add an empty directory to a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

I want to upload a empty folder to my github repo, I created the folder but...

```
mkdir foldername
touch foldername
git add foldername
git commit -m 'Added foldername'
git push origin master
```

...always gives me the following error:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: the short answer is, you cannot add empty folders

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried **following github's instructions**?

```
mkdir foldername

cd foldername
git init
touch README
git add README

git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:your_user/foldername.git
git push origin master
```

You shouldn't be `touch`ing the `foldername`, but instead **a file** inside that folder.

For example `touch README`. Or, **even better**, `touch .gitignore`.

### Explanation

Git **could track** directories since a "tree" (which corresponds to a directory) has content: the list of blobs (files) and trees (sub-directories). So git actually can (in theory) record empty directories. The **problem lies in the index file** (the staging area): it only lists files; and commits are built from the index file.

### Finding out more

If you're interested about this decision of ignoring empty directories in git you can read [this thread from the git mailing list archives](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/7/17/251902).

Answer (score 4):

Git cannot track empty directories by design (an empty directory has no content, while git tries to track content). You can add a placeholder file (an empty file ought to be enough) if you want to add the directory, or live with the limitation.